# how to show message when countdown reached to zero?

Tags: php

i got one problem where i nead your help, if you have any solution please help me.
 The problem is as follows:
    I m using $currenttime and $settime variable to set currenttime and targettime

```
$currenttime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$settime = "2012-o5-03 02:10:00";

$diff1 = abs(strtotime($currenttime) - strtotime($settime));
```

On the basis of $diff1 we are starting the countdown and countdown are working properly.

Now i want to show a message when $settime and $currenttime are equal for these i have use this code

```
 if(strtotime($currenttime) == strtotime($settime))
    {
        echo "Your time begin just now";
    }
```

but after countdown reached to zero it should show the message but it not showing, if any one have any solution plz help me.

Comment: I would change the `o` in `"2012-o5-03 02:10:00";` to a `0` :)

Comment: Is `str($settime)` a typo? it should be `strtotime($settime)`

Comment: sorry it's strtotime($settime)

Comment: Just to make sure: you're aware that this only checks the time once, right? It won't keep checking the time to see if the timer is up unless the user keeps reloading the page. For that you would need to use at least some javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have seen your code there was a little mistake with declaration such o instead of 0

& the code i wrote which is working as follow....

```
echo $currenttime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $settime = "2012-05-03 12:20:50";


$diff1 = abs(strtotime($currenttime) - strtotime($settime));

if($currenttime != $settime)
{
    echo "Your time not yet set";
}
else
{
    echo "Your time begin just now";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to compare for a time later than the expected trigger time in case the script is not running at the exact second that current and trigger time are equal.

```
if(strtotime($currenttime) >= strtotime($settime))
{
    echo "Your time begin just now";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use equal, if your script-call is a bit late, you'll never get there. use either greater then `>` to do it for all times that are PAST your goal, or check if the difference between the times is something small (like `abs(time1 - time2) < 2`), so you know your current time is  closer then 2 seconds from your target time.